# WCF WsHttpBinding Certificate Transport Security - Windows Certificate Configuration

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have two WCF Services using WsHttpBinding with transport security mutual certificate authentication that are being hosted on the same windows server.  Clients that can access one WCF service should not have access to the other WCF service.  I need some help on configuring the client certificates on the windows host.  The client certificates are signed by trusted CAs and the intermediate and root certificate chain is already installed on the the server.  It seems like the service automatically relies on chain of trust and does not require the actual client certificates installed on the server at all before letting the client access the service - this is not the behavior I want.  Can someone please tell me how I should be configuring these client certificates in order explicitly allow access to one service and not the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with certificates themselves. When using mutual SSL authentication certificates are used only to authenticate client and the authentication is done outside of your application (this is difference to message security where you can create custom certificate validator). Once certificate is trusted client is automatically authenticated to anything on the server using certificates for authentication.

You are looking for authorization - the step where you define what can authenticated client do with your service. You can either hardcode your authorization logic into your service by using [role based security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx) or you can implement two custom [`ServiceAuthorizationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774.aspx)s and assign each to single service.

Comment: thanks for the answer ladislav.  so it looks like i will have to write code in order to restrict access to the desired certificates.  in that case, i plan to write a SAM and have local configuration specifying authorized clients based on the certificate thumbprint.  can you tell me what is the correct way to determine the authenticated client certificate's thumbprint at runtime?

Comment: are you familiar with a certificate trust list (CTL)?  would i be able to configure a CTL to achieve the result?

Comment: It should be in `ClaimSet` where you will use something like `set.FindClaims(ClaimTypes.Thumbprint, Rights.Identity)` and you should get all claims with thumbprints of certificates.

Comment: CTL should probably work as well if your services are each hosted in different site (= different TCP port).

Comment: thanks again for the quick reply.  i looked deeper into CTL and from what i'm reading, it seems like it's only good for adding trusted root/intermediate CAs - not end client certificates.  can you confirm or deny this?

Comment: i don't think the CTL way will work regardless. as you were saying, it would require that the services are on different ports, but they are both on 443 - same site, different URI path.  looks like SAM is the only way to go here.  thanks for the help ladislav.

Comment: Yes it should be used with restricting CAs - it is usually used when you have control over CA and only valid clients will receive their certificate from that CA.

Comment: Btw. check [this article](http://www.leastprivilege.com/CertificateBasedAuthenticationAndWCF.aspx) and search the blog for following ones. It describes all we discussed here.